# Change rendered icon size from imported icon list image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I need to find a way to change the size of some icons i have in a single image file and are being rendered by a script module inside Visual Composer addon from Wordpress.

Example html code:

```
<ul class="ts-social-icons simple">
<li style="margin: 5px;  padding: 0px;" class="ts-social-icon  center">
    <a href="mailto:BLABLA@gmail.com" class="ts-social-email " target="_blank" style="">
        <i style="top: 9px;" class="ts-social-email"></i>
    </a>
</li>
<li style="margin: 5px;  padding: 0px;" class="ts-social-icon  center">
    <a onclick="return false" "="" href="#" class="ts-social-phone " target="_blank" style="">
        <i "="" 9px;="" top:="" class="ts-social-phone style="></i>
    </a>
</li>
<li style="margin: 5px;  padding: 0px;" class="ts-social-icon  center">
    <a onclick="return false" "="" href="#" class="ts-social-cell " target="_blank" style="">
        <i "="" top:="" class="ts-social-cell style="></i>
    </a>
</li>
<li style="margin: 5px;  padding: 0px;" class="ts-social-icon  center">
    <a href="http://www.asd.com/" class="ts-social-portfolio " target="_blank" style="">
        <i style="top: 9px; " class="ts-social-portfolio"></i>
    </a>
</li>
<li style="margin: 5px;  padding: 0px;" class="ts-social-icon  center">
    <a href="http://www.asd.com/" class="ts-social-link " target="_blank" style="">
        <i style="top: 9px; " class="ts-social-link"></i>
    </a>
</li>
<li style="margin: 5px;  padding: 0px;" class="ts-social-icon  center">
    <a href="http://https://www.facebook.com/asd" class="ts-social-facebook " target="_blank" style="">
        <i style="top: 9px; " class="ts-social-facebook"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

Current CSS

```
.ts-social-icons li a i {
  background: url("images/team-socials-black.png") no-repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

If i change the height or width here all i get are repeated icons:

```
.ts-logo-icons li a i, .ts-social-icons li a i, .ts-teammate-icons li a i {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

maybe there is a way to do it with Javascript or jquery instead of CSS?

Comment: What do you want to change the size to? Which icons? Be morespecific.

Comment: The icons are the ones with the <i> tag.

Comment: That only answers one question

Comment: I just need to know how to change the size so i can try some different sizes, check this image http://i.imgur.com/ZuBDPtY.jpg the arrow indicates the icons, i need them to occupy all the container otherwise it looks plain bad, but i might need to implement it in other places too.

Comment: Are they individual images or is it a splice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't suggest you do this with a splice, as don't have the control you want without extensively writing code that uses numeric calculations to resize the div when the user resizes the page.

Instead, I would use one of the following ways:

### First Way:

Use an `img` element instead:

```
<img width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

Then it will always resize to it's parent div (currently 20px)

---

### Second Way:

Use a `background-image` (like you already are, but not a splice), and add this:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

---

Now that you see how it's done with a single image, imagine how difficult it would be to do a splice.  But if you did want to go this route, you will need to use the 2nd way, just change it to `px` coordinates instead of `%` and change them when the page resizes (w/ something like jQuery)

Comment: That is exactly what im asking, a way to do it with jQuery, if i could choose how to dislpay it i wouldn't be asking the question, i have to work with what was provided on the question, it clearly says it is a plugin, i could add some jQuery or javascript on the header, as it says at the end of the question. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Well to write this in jQuery, you would need to know 1. the size of each icon in the splice and 2. the space in between them then 3. And hopefully they're a single row, b/c if it is a multi-row splice, even more complex and 4. and padding/whitespace around the entire image. But without you providing any of this info, how do you expect for someone to help?

Comment: Thanks man, i guess its too complicated and i will have to find another way. Dont worry.

Comment: Yea, even if there was a plugin you would most likely have to re-make the image to conform with the plugin anyhow, so cropping them would be easier most likely. I would probably just use `background-size` to test though if it's just for conceptual reasons.

Comment: Don't worry i will try to find a different way to do it. Thanks anyways.